# VS.2008 Could not retrieve the current project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-entities

In my Visual Studio 2008 i had some breakdown in my WebProject, and after reload i try to open my Linq Dasebase Model Language dbml, but the Visual Studio replys with

`Could not retrieve the current project`

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that helped me was found here:
http://forums.asp.net/post/2409651.aspx

This one solved it for me:
`devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`

Comment: You should mark this as an answer. I encountered the same situation and your solution fixed my issue. Thank you.